# P5JS sound only plays when I leave the active tab

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to write a code so that when a rect() reaches a certain point, a song will start playing. I was having trouble with my actual code so I started a new test file to mess around with it and try to get it to work (my actual js file is very long & I wanted something short and simple) but I just ran into the problem again.

The code is supposed to work so if the mouse is pressed, the left square will slide over to the right square, and when it hits the right square, the song will play. If the mouse is clicked again, the song will stop.

I've gotten most of that to work, but the trouble comes in when I add in

```
if ( backtoblack.isPlaying() ) {
    backtoblack.stop();
  } else {
    backtoblack.play();
  }
```

Here's the complete code for the sketch:

```
var backtoblack;
var rect1X = 20;
var speed = 1;
var mouseWasPressed; 


function preload(){

    backtoblack = loadSound('assets/backtoblack.mp3');
}


function setup() {

    createCanvas(590,630);
    background("#704e34");
}


function draw(){

    fill("#fff");

    rect(rect1X, 20, 120, 120);

    rect(450, 20, 120, 120);

    if (mouseWasPressed == true ) {

        if(rect1X <= 390){

            rect1X += speed;
        }
    }

    if ( backtoblack.isPlaying() ) {
        backtoblack.stop();
    } else {
        backtoblack.play();
    } 
}  

function mousePressed(){
    mouseWasPressed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `if else` block that toggles whether the song is playing is inside the `draw()` function. That means that 60 times per second, you toggle the song! It's like you're constantly hitting the play and stop buttons. Then when you switch tabs, the `draw()` function is paused, which is why it stops toggling.

To fix your problem, you need to not toggle the song every frame. Perhaps put it inside the `mousePressed()` function to test things out.

Taking a step back, I'd also encourage you to [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) (that guide is for Processing, but [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) is a guide on JavaScript). It's really great that you put together a smaller example program to test things out, but you should also try to step through the code line by line, or add print statements, to figure out what's going on. Stepping through or adding print statements would have helped you realize what was going on.

Anyway, good luck!